# How to change source binding of a project or solution through code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfsbuild, visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-plugin

My question is very simple. How to change the source control binding of a solution (or Project) that I have at my local machine (C:\ or somewhere), **not through Visual Studio UI but through C# code. Is there any library for that?**

I know there is a SourceSafeType library which I used for automating a whole bunch of other tasks on VSS, but I couldn't find any API for changing source binding of a solution or a project

Comment: Can you explain more about your usage scenario? Why do you need to chang the source binding through code?

Comment: We have a manual process where after every major market release, we create a branch for the next release cycle. And we have local copies for each cycle. So when creating the new branch I "Get Latest" from old one to a local location and then put it back in VSS again. So for all the solutions I have to change the binding manually. Hence I want to automate it

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the steps like below? I think this would be easier for you to manage the code versions.

1. After a major release, create a branch for your solution in VSS Explorer.
2. In Visual Studio, use [Open from Source Control command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9zzhatx(v=vs.90).aspx) to connect to your new branch and retrieve it.
3. You can then work on the new branch for future dev.